# Upload file com CakePHP

Tags: cakephp, upload

Referente ao upload file, tenho os seguintes códigos até o agora:

**Controller:**

```js
public
 function initialize()  {
     parent::initialize(); 
     $this - > loadComponent('Upload');
 }

 public
 function upload() {
     if (!empty($this - > request - > data)) {
         $this - > Upload -> send($this - > request - > data['uploadfile']); 
     }
 }
```

**view:**

```
<?php echo $this->Form->create(null, ['type' => 'file']); ?>
            <label>Arquivos</label>
<?php 
    echo $this->Form->file('uploadfile.', ['multiple']);
    echo $this->Form->button('Submit', ['type' => 'submit']);
    echo $this->Form->end();
?>
```

Esta funcionando, mas preciso inserir essa *view* dentro de outra view (no caso, dentro de um formulário de abertura de chamado), que esta com esse código:

**view "add"**

```
<?php
    echo $this->Form->input('id' );
    echo $this->Form->input('titulo');
    echo $this->Form->input('ip');
    echo $this->Form->input('mensagem');
?>
```

Mas se eu simplesmente colar a *view* que funciona dentro da *view* de abertura de chamado, não da nenhum erro, mas minha imagem upada não vai para a pasta de destino. Acredito que possa ser alguma coisa pra arrumar no *controller* da função "Add", o código dela esta assim:

**Controller**

```
public
function add() {
    $post = $this -> Posts -> newEntity();
    if ($this -> request -> is(['post', 'put'])) {
        $this -> Posts -> patchEntity($post, $this - > request - > data);
        $post -> user_id = $this - > Auth -> user('id');


        if ($this -> Posts -> save($post)) {
            $this -> Flash -> success(__('Chamado enviado, aguarde resposta... '));
            return $this -> redirect(['action' => 'listar']);
        }
        $this -> Flash -> error(__('Chamado não enviado'));
    }
    $this -> set(compact('post'));

}
```

Eu acho que se eu conseguisse chamar a função "upload" para dentro da função "add", resolveria o problema, mas como posso fazer isso?

Comment: Aonde você esta configurando o caminho que vai fazer o upload?

Comment: Voce diz,  o caminho em que os arquivos ficarão salvos? se sim, estou configurando no component, "UploadComponent"

Comment: Eu não sei como o CakePHP funciona, já que uso mais frequentemente o CodeIgniter, mas acho que tinha que ter a função PHP `move_uploaded_file` em algum lugar aí, não?

Comment: Tem sim, mas dentro da classe UploadComponent:                                             move_uploaded_file($file_tmp_name, $dir.DS.Text::uuid().'-'.$filename);

Answer (score 1):

Você deve manter o **['type' => 'file']** como um dos parâmetros presentes no método create() ao criar um formulário que deva fazer upload de arquivos, do contrário o arquivo não será transferido.

Comment: Exatamente, conforme você passou assim: `<?php echo $this->Form->create(null, ['type' => 'file']); ?>`